# Pause input counters incrementing when imaging a device through USB NIC

Tags: nic, usb, sccm, qos, cisco-catalyst

We keep running into issues with trying to image devices using a usb-e1000 NIC.  It will get the OS on there, but then once that happens the "pause input" counter on the switch begins to increment and the imaging job fails out.  This is when using a cisco 3850.

If we try it on a 2960, the pxe boot process just never starts and the pause input counter just increments until it errors out.

The USB nic is a Plugable branded model usb3-E1000

If you put a dumb switch in between the two devices, the pause input counter doesn't increment at all.

Anyone run into this at all?  Is it a driver issue or maybe an ios issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

The driver windows uses for the e1000 device is automatically downloaded from windows update.  We had it for the winPE, but not windows.  So one the os was loaded it iddn't have a driver and dropped the connection.

Adding the driver to the image seems to have fixed the issue.